# Python acting a little strange over MQTT and JSON when using the FTP lib

Tags: python, json, ftp

I currently have a Python script that will send a instructions along information to another Python script over MQTT in JSON.

The message looks something like this:

```
{"ftp_port": "21", "ftp_username": "test", "ftp_ip": "192.168.2.29", "ftp_password": "test", "folder_save": "test2"}
```

As you can see, from this JSON msg I grab the information I need and upload what my script makes onto an FTP. And here's the tricky part...

This is part of my FTP upload script:

```
        data = json.loads(msg.payload)
        ftp_ip = data['ftp_ip']
        ftp_port = data['ftp_port']
        ftp_username = data['ftp_username']
        ftp_password = data['ftp_password']
        ftp = ftplib.FTP()
        try:
                ftp.connect(ftp_ip, ftp_port)
                print "FTP: Connecting!"
        except Exception, e:
                print str(e)
        try:
                ftp.login(ftp_username, ftp_password)
                print "FTP: Logging in!"
```

The script returns the following error:

> getaddrinfo() argument 2 must be integer or string

Although it doesn't really give much information, I found out that it's from the first try clause, and it can't read either the IP or the port properly. Replacing it with an actual IP instead of what comes from JSON will work perfectly fine.

Note how the username and password from the JSON doesn't give me trouble?

I'm not sure what's happening here or how to fix it. When I add a clause that prints out the data['ftp_ip'] it comes up exactly how it should be.

Any help would be grateful welcomed!

Comment: have you tried `ftp.connect(ftp_ip, int(ftp_port))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ftp.connect(ftp_ip, ftp_port)
```

`ftp_port` is a string. On my machine (Python 3.4) I get a different error but somehow similar:

```
    if port > 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

do that instead:

```
ftp.connect(ftp_ip, int(ftp_port))
```

(or convert directly: `ftp_port = int(data['ftp_port'])`)